# TTS Error: leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech

Tags: android

### Solution

It appears you must call the super method in onActivityResult

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

---

I am getting this error from TTS when I press the back button on my Activity.  Aparently it is because I am not calling shutdown() but I am, see onDestroy() below.  I have made an abstract TtsActivity Class which Activities Extend.  I am calling super.onDestroy() in all subclasses.

```
12-05 18:04:05.268: ERROR/ActivityThread(30240): Activity com.mysite.myapp.ActivitySelectItGame has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$1@43e9b4a0 that was originally bound here
12-05 18:04:05.268: ERROR/ActivityThread(30240): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.mysite.myapp.ActivitySelectItGame has leaked ServiceConnection android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$1@43e9b4a0 that was originally bound here
12-05 18:04:05.268: ERROR/ActivityThread(30240):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(ActivityThread.java:1121)
12-05 18:04:05.268: ERROR/ActivityThread(30240):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.getServiceDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:1016)
12-05 18:04:05.268: ERROR/ActivityThread(30240):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:863)
12-05 18:04:05.268: ERROR/ActivityThread(30240):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:347)
12-05 18:04:05.268: ERROR/ActivityThread(30240):     at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.initTts(TextToSpeech.java:467)
12-05 18:04:05.268: ERROR/ActivityThread(30240):     at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.<init>(TextToSpeech.java:433)
12-05 18:04:05.268: ERROR/ActivityThread(30240):     at com.mysite.android.library.activity.ActivityTTS.onActivityResult(ActivityTTS.java:98)
12-05 18:04:05.268: ERROR/ActivityThread(30240):     at com.mysite.myapp.ActivityGame.onActivityResult(ActivityGame.java:445)
12-05 18:04:05.268: ERROR/ActivityThread(30240):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3890)
12-05 18:04:05.268: ERROR/ActivityThread(30240):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3511)
12-05 18:04:05.268: ERROR/ActivityThread(30240):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3557)
12-05 18:04:05.268: ERROR/ActivityThread(30240):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-05 18:04:05.268: ERROR/ActivityThread(30240):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2063)
12-05 18:04:05.268: ERROR/ActivityThread(30240):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-05 18:04:05.268: ERROR/ActivityThread(30240):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-05 18:04:05.268: ERROR/ActivityThread(30240):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-05 18:04:05.268: ERROR/ActivityThread(30240):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 18:04:05.268: ERROR/ActivityThread(30240):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-05 18:04:05.268: ERROR/ActivityThread(30240):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-05 18:04:05.268: ERROR/ActivityThread(30240):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-05 18:04:05.268: ERROR/ActivityThread(30240):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The Activity that my classes are extending

```
public abstract class ActivityTTS extends Activity implements OnInitListener {
    //TEXT TO SPEECH SERVICE
    public static final int CHECK_TTS_AVAILABILITY = 101;
    private static final String TAG = "ActivityTTS";
    private TextToSpeech mTts; //Text to speech library

    //MESSAGES
    private String NO_TTS_ANDROID_MARKET_REDIRECT = 
            "'SpeechSynthesis Data Installer' is not installed on your system, you are being redirected to" +
            " the installer package. You may also be able to install it my going to the 'Home Screen' then " +
            "(Menu -> Settings -> Voice Input & output -> Text-to-speech settings)";
    private String NO_TTS_AVAILABLE = 
            "'SpeechSynthesis Data Installer' is not available on your system, " +
            "you may have to install it manually yourself. You may also be able to install it my going to the 'Home Screen' " +
            "then (Menu -> Settings -> Voice Input & output -> Text-to-speech settings)";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() called in ActivityTTS");

        try { //A weird error was occurring on some phones with the TTS, hence the try catch
            //TTS Service
            Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
            checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
            startActivityForResult(checkIntent, CHECK_TTS_AVAILABILITY);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, NO_TTS_AVAILABLE, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }

    }






    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


    }






    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }



    /**
     * Add a custom audio file for a particular 
     * audio element.
     * 
     * @param text
     * @param filename
     */
    protected void addSpeech(String text, String filename ) {
        mTts.addSpeech(text, filename);
    }



    /**
     * For TTS
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try {
            //Log.d(TAG, "TTS Response: "+requestCode);
            if (requestCode == CHECK_TTS_AVAILABILITY) {
                if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {

                    // success, create the TTS instance
                    this.mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

                } else {
                    // missing data, install it
                    Toast.makeText(this, NO_TTS_ANDROID_MARKET_REDIRECT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                    Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                    installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                    ResolveInfo resolveInfo = pm.resolveActivity( installIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY );

                    if( resolveInfo == null ) {
                       // Not able to find the activity which should be started for this intent
                        Toast.makeText(this, NO_TTS_AVAILABLE, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                       startActivity( installIntent );
                    }

                    finish();
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to access service");
            finish();
        }

    }




    /**
     * Loads when the TTS is ready
     */
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        mTts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
    }


    /**
     * Speak text
     */
    protected void speak(String text) {
        try{
            mTts.stop(); //Stop speaking
            mTts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "TTS Failed - cannot say: "+text );
        }
    }


    /**
     * Speak a pre-recorded word
     */
    protected void speak(String text, File filename) {
        try{
            mTts.stop(); //Stop speaking
            mTts.addSpeech(text, filename.toString());
            mTts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "TTS Failed - cannot say: "+text );
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        //Close the Text to Speech Library
        if(mTts != null) {

            mTts.stop();
            mTts.shutdown();
            Log.d(TAG, "TTS Destroyed");
        }
    }

    public void setLanguage(Locale audioLocale) {
        mTts.setLanguage(audioLocale);
    }
}
```

Here is the code related the the activity in ActivityGame

```
public abstract class ActivityGame extends ActivityTTS {

...

    protected void speak() {
        if (Logging.INFO) Log.i(TAG, "Speaking");

        if(this.mVoicePreference) {
            String word = mBoundService.getCurrentWord().getSpelling();


            if(WordRecordingHelper.recordingExists(word)) {

                try{
                    File f = new File(Constants.SDCARD_RECORDINGS+WordRecordingHelper.formatRecordedWord(word));
                    super.addSpeech(word, f.getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    if(Logging.WARN) Log.w(TAG, "An error occurred while trying to use addSpeech()", e);
                }
            }


            //play the audio
            super.speak(word);  
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        ...

        }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        ....
        }


}
```

And here is ActivitySelectItGame, it doe not reference TTS at all, just extends ActivityGame

```
public class ActivitySelectItGame extends ActivityGame {
    ...
}
```

But I get the exact same problem from a totally unrelated Activity the extends ActivityTTS.

Comment: Where do you set a value in mTts?

Comment: @gnobal I updated the question to add lots more information

Comment: I believe the solution that you mentioned is incorrect.  In my case, I had to make sure onDestroy() is fully executed before creating a new instance.

Answer (score 47):

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {


    //Close the Text to Speech Library
    if(mTts != null) {

        mTts.stop();
        mTts.shutdown();
        Log.d(TAG, "TTS Destroyed");
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

I think the problem is you are clsoing the mTts after the activity is destroyed. Try to use the code i have posted. Let me know if this works out

Comment: Is it possible for u show code related to mTts in ActivitySelectItGame

Comment: I updated the question, but I get the exact same error from a totally unrelated Activity that extends ActivityTTS

Answer (score 15):

Each time you create an instance of mtts you need to `shutdown` it.

Or in other words, if you have more than one of `new TextToSpeech(xxx)` you need to have the same number of `shutdown()`.

This works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that onDestroy() is always called by the system. I've seen instances of it being skipped in my emulator. I can't reproduce the circumstances every time though.
I've used TTS and have no problems with leaks. **I call the mTts.shutdown() in onPause()** and reinitialise it in onResume(). This works fine for me.

Comment: It does in fact call onDestroy because I see my Log.d statements in the Android log before the error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

`onCreate()`, where you start the activity for result in order to check whether TTS is available, can be called by the framework many times. So I think you may be creating multiple TTS instances in `onActivityResult()`. For more information, see [the diagram for the Activity class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). Note that `onCreate()` can be called again after a call to `onStop()`

Comment: I had the same error calling only once onCreate() - but it was called also after returning form a dialog. That was the pb tnx

Answer (score 2):

I got this Leaked Connection when using a WebView in my Fragment. In the onCreateView method I did setJavaScriptEnabled(true), which caused this error, when pressing back on the Activity. To get rid of it, I moved the set to onResume(), and also set it to false in onPause(), then problem disappeared.